# Cortex M3 delay 1us

Tags: c, assembly, cortex-m3

Im trying to achieve 1us delay to be able to drive 1-wire bus. 
My proc is working on 10Mhz PCLK so I tried to use timer function with overflow on 10th cycle. For some reason it gives me resolution of 6.2ish us. Don't know why...

```
void _delay_us (int a_us)
{
LPC_TIM_TypeDef *timer = LPC_TIM0;
timer->MCR=0X0000000A; 
timer->TCR=0x02; //reset timer
timer->TC=0;
timer->PC=0;
timer->PR = 0x00000000;
timer->MR0=a_us;
timer->TCR=0x01; //start timer
while(timer->TC!=timer->MR0); //wait here up to match
}
```

Next tryout was to "waste" 10 cycles with asm nop (which by the [documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/I1010015.html) should take 1 32bit instruction), but that also didn't work (example is only 3 nops, which takes around 0.6us, regardless of number of nops) ... Now that is a puzzle. for loop should take 4 cycles for a_us = 1 ?  where did other 2 came from?

```
void _delay_us (int a_us)
{
int i;
for(i=0; i<a_us; ++i){
    __asm__ volatile (
       "nop\n\t"
       "nop\n\t"
       "nop\n\t"    );
       }
 }
```

But compiler seems to optimize nop's without taking any proc cycle ...

What I did is this loop:

```
void _delay_us (int a_us)
{
int i;
int a, b;
for(i=0; i<a_us; ++i){
        for (a=0;a<6;a++){
        b++;
        }
       }
}
```

This is totally heuristic approach, measured by oscilloscope. If i count it right it should make 21 ops (i guess 16bit's), so it should be around 10 cycles ?. 
It gives around 1us delay, but i dont like it ...

Is there any better way to achieve 1us delay ?

Comment: Check the disassembly listing and you understand why your asm-nop-timing is so far off. Quite a bit of code will be around the nop's to fit them in the compiled code. Not sure how to list the disassembly for your toolchain though

Comment: Ok, ill take a look at IDE options if it is possible to get asm listing.

Comment: @jippie - I'm curious why you think there will be a lot of code framing the nop's "to fit them in the compiled code" - as instructions which shouldn't modify registers or flags, why would that be the case?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Pretty standard to push and pop some register to/from stack (optional extra register load / store instructions to pass parameters), but you can't tell for sure if you don't check the code. I checked it couple times for AVR and I was amazed by how many instructions are added around couple simple assembler instructions. The compiler may not be aware of which registers will be used.

Comment: @jippie - that's pretty odd, typically you have to tell the compiler what registers you want to use, or save them yourself.  Otherwise, one that simply guesses would give the inefficient - and generally undesirable - situation you ran into.  I'd agree with checking the listing of course, but mostly to see that the compiler hasn't optimized the whole thing out.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get accurate timing in a microcontroller, you really need to be setting up the hardware timer to interrupt at the exact time you specify rather than polling with software and then comparing to a value.
Your cpu probably can't even take in all that data and process it in time before the next event is supposed to happen.
The hardware is specifically made to have accurate timing on events.

It sounds like you might be trying to generate some kind of waveform using these delay values.  If so, these can typically be programmed using the "output compare" function of a timer, which could toggle an output port exactly when a specified timer value is reached.

Comment: "to drive 1-wire bus"

Comment: Totally agree- hardware timers / interrupts are the way to do this, although many buses (I2C, SPI, etc., especially where one device is master and the other is slave) will allow timing to drift or vary across a wide range and it rarely needs to be accurate, as long as you're going fast enough for the data transfer rate required.

Comment: Im not sure how would i achieve 1wire communication with using hardware interrupt unless i put all the code in int routine and drive it with some kind of state machine, but then again it would complicate things unnecessary. If it is signalGen, then i would opt for your suggestion.

Comment: @Gossamer - indeed, it's an awkward answer, or more likely not based on careful reading to understand your need.  Rather surprised it's been upvoted.

Comment: @Gossamer You mention that you can achieve approximate 1us delay but you "dont like it".  If you want to be more accurate as well as periodic in your timing, then interrupts with a state machine is a good idea and I have done this for I2C.  If accuracy isn't too important, then it looks like you already found your answer by implementing loops of nops and trying to keep the compiler optimizations from interfering. An alternate option would be to just set up the interrupt to wait for the timer delay and then launch an event of your choice.

Comment: @Gossamer Even if you don't use an interrupt routine, you could still use the hardware timer rather than a nop loop.  You are already needing to pay attention to the assembly code optimization, so perhaps you could poll for the timer match flag (instead of using a software equality comparator) in order to avoid any other software delays incurred.  If you insist on using a software loop, then I agree with your answer where it is written in assembly and made to be "inline."

Comment: You mean in assembly, instead of using NOP to look at timer value ?

Comment: I'm just referring to the fact that you have the line `while(timer->TC!=timer->MR0)` in your code which seems to be reading the timer value and then comparing it to the count limit that you specified.  There is usually a flag in the hardware timer that you can use to check if a certain count has been met (something like Timer Output Compare), and the flag will stay set until clear it.

Answer (score 1):

What i end up with, is assembler routine without using C around it as i tried before with loop and nops..

```
__asm void _delay_us (int a_us)
{
    CBZ R0, end
    MOV R1, #14
loop2
    MOV R2, R0

loop        
    NOP
    SUB R2, R2, #1
    CMP R2, #0
    BNE loop
    SUB R1, R1, #1
    CMP R1, #0
    BNE loop2
end
    BX lr
}
```

This way i dont have to worry on how will it end up in asm code, it just use it as it is.

One further optimization would be to use `inline` function. That way i would not loose few more cycles to store registers, load function, execute it, restore resister ... But then it would enlarge final ROM size.

Answer (score 0):

There will be plenty of bookkeeping associated with the interrupt handler -- copying and storing the contents of the program pointer and important registers, and then restoring them when the interrupt is done.  I suspect this will behave like fixed overhead, but it may have to do with your toolchain. You could probably write your own interrupt handler if you're 100% sure about what registers you need to hold on to and what you could throw away, but for a 1us delay, interrupt isn't the first approach I would try. Noops is what I would use, and as mentioned earlier, you'll need to pay attention to the assembly that your compiler gives you.

Comment: Easiest way to pay attention to assembly is to use assembly :) It took me few hours to retract things from back of my brain and write few lines of asm, but it worked out at the end.

Comment: Note that the original isn't using an interrupt handler, but merely waiting for a condition - a condition which could also be used as an interrupt trigger, but isn't apparently.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, good point.  Maybe interrupt would have been the way to go.